# Select required attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, contact-form, required

How can I make the select form required? I tried putting "required" but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel2">How many years have you been trading *</label>
    <select  class="form-control" id="sel2" required>
        <option>Please select one</option>
        <option>Start Up</option>
        <option value="1-2">1-3</option>
        <option value="3-4">3-4</option>
        <option value="5more">5 or more</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Also for this one, I just got this from a website and I downloaded the zip file but I need to add a required attribute

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Country *</label><br>
    <div id="basic" data-input-name="country" required></div>
</div>


 <script>
$('#basic').flagStrap();

$('#origin').flagStrap({
    placeholder: {
        value: "",
        text: "Country of origin"
    }
});

$('#options').flagStrap({
    countries: {
        "AU": "Australia",
        "GB": "United Kingdom",
        "US": "United States"
    },
    buttonSize: "btn-sm",
    buttonType: "btn-info",
    labelMargin: "10px",
    scrollable: false,
    scrollableHeight: "350px"
});

$('#advanced').flagStrap({
    buttonSize: "btn-lg",
    buttonType: "btn-primary",
    labelMargin: "20px",
    scrollable: false,
    scrollableHeight: "350px",
    onSelect: function (value, element) {
        alert(value);
        console.log(element);
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Required is not woking here because you have not set valued in all option.Set values in first two options:

```
<link href="view/css/flags.css" rel="stylesheet">

<select  class="form-control" id="sel2" required>
       <option value="">Please select one</option>
       <option  value="startup">Start Up</option>
       <option value="1-2">1-3</option>
       <option value="3-4">3-4</option>
       <option value="5more">5 or more</option>
 </select>

<script>
$('#basic').flagStrap();

$('#origin').flagStrap({
    placeholder: {
        value: "",
        text: "Country of origin"
    }
});

$('#options').flagStrap({
    countries: {
        "AU": "Australia",
        "GB": "United Kingdom",
        "US": "United States"
    },
    buttonSize: "btn-sm",
    buttonType: "btn-info",
    labelMargin: "10px",
    scrollable: false,
    scrollableHeight: "350px"
});

$('#advanced').flagStrap({
    buttonSize: "btn-lg",
    buttonType: "btn-primary",
    labelMargin: "20px",
    scrollable: false,
    scrollableHeight: "350px",
    onSelect: function (value, element) {
        alert(value);
        console.log(element);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: they make no sense as options anyway

Comment: he need to set null value in "Please select one" option , but in "Start up" option may be have some value which i dont know..so i have just put null

Comment: @Dagon Have you been trading for Start Up number of years as well?

Comment: @DharaParmar I tried putting values in it still not working :(

Comment: @Nnn What value did you use for `Please select one`?

Comment: @Mike value="selectone"

Comment: Set null in value of "Please select one" so it will  be..<option value="">Please select one</option>

Comment: If you put null value in any of the option then only required will work

Comment: @DharaParmar Calling an empty string a "null value" is confusing.

Comment: I mean to say value=""  it means value is empty

Comment: @DharaParmar Yes I understand that. It's just that in programming languages `null` is a special value and is completely different than an empty string (however it can often be type-cast to an empty string).

Comment: Ok mike..but here the point is to set value=""...

Comment: @DharaParmar it worked now thank you!!

Comment: @DharaParmar but what about for the second part? The country selector?

Comment: what does the "basic" div contains?

Comment: @DharaParmar I have no idea lol I just copy-pasted it. I edited my question and added the script can you please take a look at it?